# Can you map an iteration to a column on your TFS board?

Tags: tfs, storyboard, agile, scrum

My team has our backlog, sprint backlog, and sprint. On our board we have New (backlog), Ready (sprint backlog), Active (sprint), Resolved and Closed.

Is there any way to map the sprint backlog (defined as an iteration) to the TFS board or do I need to move over each story manually?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to do that. Unfortunately, there's not much more commentary that can be added. You can make a suggestion on UserVoice and other people can vote for the feature if they'd like to see it added.